# The passwords is different and I can see the published messages?

Tags: mqtt, messagebroker, paho, android-open-accessory

In the below code snippet I declare a `username` and `passqord` for the subscription.

```
private final String userName = "user_1";
private final char[] password = "pass".toCharArray();
....
....
final MqttAndroidClient client_1 = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), serverURI,   
clientID, persistenceDataDir, Ack.AUTO_ACK);
MqttConnectOptions opts = new MqttConnectOptions();
opts.setCleanSession(false);
opts.setWill(WILL_TOPIC, WILL_MSG.getBytes(), QoS, false);
opts.setKeepAliveInterval(keepAliveInterval);
opts.setUserName(userName);
opts.setPassword(password);
```

I started the connection from the App with `clean session = false` and `client ID = 1` without passwoed and username Provided, and I kept publishing (from the Pc to the broker) values of a topic I have subscribed to (from the App to the Broker.

Later in the `subscribe` message I set a pasword and username in my connection options, and did not specify the username and password to the `publish` message, and re-run the p. what happens is, I recieved the updated published values of the topic i am subsribed to.

After that, in the `publish` i specified a wrong username and password and subscriped to the same topic, and when i run the App, i receive the values normaly.

I am using the password and username wrongly?

**To Note**: I have tried the same procedure with different `clientID` and i receive the published values even with wrong password specified.

Comment: This totally depends what you have configured on your broker. Which MQTT broker are you using and how did you configure the accepted username and password?

Comment: i am using mosquitto and when i publish a message i set the user name using "-u" and the password using "-P", and at subscribing, as i am using paho Android API, i use the "mqttConnectOptions" e.g: options.setUsername(username)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a acl file and a password file in order to make usernames and passwords to control access to topics.

Please read the mosqitto.conf and mosquitto_passwd man pages for details of the format of both these files

http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_passwd-1.html